# App will not open and will crash on every attempt

Tags: applications, crash

Whenever I open an app it goes there for a second then crashes and goes directly to the home screen. This haven't happened before, it recently started.
I have restarted my phone, powered it off, and updated to the latest iOS.
Is there anything I can do to fix this other than reinstalling the application?

Answer (score 1):

No, the app is either corrupted (which happens sometimes during the download) or as a serious defect that causes it to crash (and that Apple didn't catch during review).

You'll have to uninstall then reinstall the app.